# choose.dir does not work in RStudio-Server

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

choose.dir command does not work in my function when I run it from RStudio-Server.

```
mywd = choose.dir(caption = 'Where do you want to save the results?')
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in choose.dir(caption = "Where do you want to save the results?") : 
  could not find function "choose.dir"
```

No problems in RStudio itself when run locally. Only on RStudio Server. Has anyone experience this as well?

Comment: Are you trying to open a directory on the server? Because that's potentially a security risk. There is also a note on the `?choose.dir` help page that says "This is only available on Windows." It's unlikely that your RStudio Server is running on Windows. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Also since this seems to be a question specifically about an RStudio product, you are likely to get better help at https://community.rstudio.com/.

Comment: Many thanks for pointing this out. As the server is Linux, this is probably why it was failing. Is there an alternative command to do the same in Linux via R?